# How to fix this error: begin (possibly implicit): no expression after a sequence of internal definitions

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm having problems implementing one generator called `fib` in a function.
I want the function to return me a generator that generates the first `n` Fibonacci numbers.

```
 ;THIS IS MY GENERATOR

 (define fib
  (let ((a 0) (b 1))
    (lambda ()
      (let ((return a))
        (set! a b)
        (set! b (+ b return)
        )return))))

 ;THIS IS MY FUNCTION
  (define (take n g)  
  (define fib
    (let ((a 0) (b 1) (cont 1))
      (lambda ()
        (if (>= cont n) #f
            (let ((return a))
              (set! cont (+ cont 1))
              (set! a b)
              (set! b (+ b return)
                    )(return)))))))
```

I expect a generator to return the Fibonacci numbers up to `N` (delivered to the function). But the actual output is :

> *begin (possibly implicit): no expression after a sequence of internal definitions in:*
>
> ```
> (begin 
>     (define fib 
>        (let ((a 0) (b 1) (cont 1)) 
>           (lambda () 
>             (if (>= cont n) #f 
>               (let ((return a)) 
>                  (set! cont (+ cont 1)) 
>                  (set! a b) 
>                  (set! b (+ b return)) 
>                  (return)))))))
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the error says, you have no expressions in your function's definition except for some internal definition (which, evidently, is put into an implicit `begin`). Having defined it, what is a function to do?

More importantly, there's problems with your solution's overall design.

When writing a function's definition, write down its sample calls right away, so you see how it is supposed / intended / to be called. In particular,

```
  (define (take n g)
```

suggests you intend to call it like `(take 10 fib)`, so that inside `take`'s definition `g` will get the value of `fib`.

But `fib` is one *global* generator. It's not restartable in any way between different calls to it. That's why you started copying its source, but then realized perhaps, why have the `g` parameter, then? Something doesn't fit quite right, there.

You need instead a way to create a new, *fresh* Fibonacci generator when you need to:

```
(define (mk-fib)
  (let ((a 0) (b 1))
    (lambda ()
      (let ((ret a))
        (set! a b)
        (set! b (+ ret b))
        ret))))    ;; ..... as before .....
```

Now each `(mk-fib)` call will create and return a new, fresh Fibonacci numbers generator, so it now *can* be used as an argument to a `take` call:

```
(define (taking n g)      ;; (define q (taking 4 (mk-fib)))
```

Now there's no need to be defining a new, local copy of the same global `fib` generator, as you were trying to do before. We just have whatever's specific to the `take` itself:

```
   (let ((i 1))
     (lambda ()         ; a generator interface is a function call
       (if (> i n)      ; not so good: what if #f
           #f           ;  is a legitimately produced value?
           (begin
             (set! i (+ i 1))
             (g))))))   ; a generator interface is a function call
```

Now we can define

```
> (define q (taking 4 (mk-fib)))
> (q)
0
> (q)
1
> (q)
1
> (q)
2
> (q)
#f
> (q)
#f
>
```